# I'm getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" with the same domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, same-origin-policy

Well my JavaScript calls the url that is the part of the website, so I have no idea why this is "cross-origin".

My AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: SITE_URL+'ajax_check.php?p='+P_ID,
    //let's say SITE_URL is http://example.com/dev
    success:function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

And this is the error I get in firebug:

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/dev/ajax_check.php?p=23. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Comment: Define "basically part of the website". Either it is or it isn't.  My guess is that it isn't, and either the current page or target page is at a different port or protocol.  https://example.com isn't the same as http://example.com.

Comment: The only time I see this is when I forget to use localhost and open it as a local file resource (i.e. double-clicking the index.html file).

Comment: We aren't better judges of cross-origin requests than your browser is. If it says it's a different domain, it ***is*** a different domain. What matters is: what is the exact URL shown in the browser when viewing this page (including protocol, subdomains, and port number) and what is the exact URL of the request (including protocol, subdomains, and port number).

Comment: could be www against non-www... give me a minute.

Comment: Local file resources have different restrictions (more restrictive) than web addresses. Do everything as localhost and you'll be fine.

Comment: I think my server redirects the traffic to www, but not ajax calls. adding www to the ajax reguest solves it. I love you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by VoteyDisciple the url format must be exactly the same. In my situation the page url had a www prefix, but the ajax call url did not. So that's "cross-origin".